# How does iptables MASQUERADE work on the incoming side?

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, route

I'm still reading the iptables manual page and other documents and 
digging around questions and their answers.

This is the problem which arises.
When we setup the NAT we use a POSTROUTING rule such as this:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE -o eth0
```

It seems when a packet hits this chain then an internal host needs to initialize
some connection with the internet right? Incoming traffic will route through the same path without hitting the chain? Am I right on this?

Answer (score 5):

The POSTROUTING chain is checked for all packets which leave the system, even the locally generated ones (they leave out PREROUTING and use OUTPUT instead).

The rule is limited to traffic which is outgoing via `eth0`. "Incoming" is every traffic being routed (if you related this to POSTROUTING). You probably mean traffic from the Internet (`eth0`). Usually traffic which comes in on `eth0` will not leave the system via `eth0`.

POSTROUTING affects outgoing traffic only (and only the first packet of a connection). If replies arrive on `eth0` then they are recognized as part of the SNAT connection and their destination address (and port) are automatically translated to their original values (those overwritten by the `MASQUERADE` target).

Comment: Yes eth0 is the internet connection. So incoming connections to the eth0 will not hit that POSTROUTING chain in NAT table but it will be considered as SNAT and will be translated to their original values?

Comment: I'm asking this question because, we didn't explicitly didn't mention such this. It's happening implicitly. Am I right on that.

Comment: @sandundhammika For each incoming packet the connection tracking checks whether it is part of a known connection. If it belongs to a known connection and the outgoing parts of this connection are masqueraded then the automatic translation takes place. This does not affect incoming packets which create a new connection.

Answer (score 3):

In iptables only the first packet of a connection hits the chains in the nat table (this is different from chains in other tables). Packets related to an existing connection are translated automatically based on the mappings that were established when the first packet was processed.

If an incoming packet arrives that does not match an existing connection and doesn't match a rule in the NAT table then it will be processed without NAT (which may involve forwarding it, passing it up the protocol stack locally or dropping it depending on the destination IP and iptables rules in other tables).