# Add internet to bridge with NAT

Tags: iptables, virtual-machine, routing, qemu

My setup is several VM's, with a local subnet (192.168.10.0/24)

Host machine is 192.168.10.1 (br1) (or 10.30.0.7 interface with inet) it runs a DHCP server to assign my VM's their IP's.

I don't want to bridge the connection like normal with brctl addif but instead I want the VM's to be able to connect to the internet sharing the host's IP (specifically 10.30.0.1 or interface wg0 (wireguard))

How can I do this with iptables?

Comment: You're looking for "[tag:nat]" (or possibly "masquerade"). I'm sure you'll find many answers here with that keyword

Comment: This simple rule does it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78320/how-does-iptables-masquerade-work-on-the-incoming-side

Comment: that's good to hear you've found an answer. Can we mark yours as a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does iptables MASQUERADE work on the incoming side?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78320/how-does-iptables-masquerade-work-on-the-incoming-side)